# Content Assist not working in Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've been working in Eclipse programming for Android for about a year now. I suddenly have an enormous problem. Here is the error:

> "Content Assist" did not complete
>   normally.  Please see the log for more
>   information.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I go to Help>About Eclipse SDK>Installation Details>Configuration>View Error Log and it is nothing but a blank page. No errors at all.

I tried researching online. The most relevant pages I could find are http://forums.adobe.com/thread/455543 and http://www.themorphicgroup.com/blog/2009/10/27/content-assist-did-not-complete-normally/ and http://www.airtightinteractive.com/2010/01/fix-for-flash-builder-content-assist-did-not-complete-normally/ . All of these pages say to close FB, delete the .metadata folder,restart FB, import/export some SWC file, and/or delete some file with "flexbuilder" in it's name. None of these work and I see nothing on my whole machine with any of "Flash Builder", "FB", "flex", or "flexbuilder" in it's name.

As a desperate last resort I deleted all traces of Eclipse, Android, Adobe *anything*, and Java from my machine.

Absolutely no difference what-so-ever. Besides exhaustion and heartache for me.

The content assist features seem to work fine in java files (for now anyway). It seems that only .xml files are affected.

What can I do to resolve or work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the correct editor is opening the xml files. I have aptana and some other plugins that support xml files. Right click the file in project explorer and select open with, then select Android Xml Editor and see if you have completion.

I dont know if that is the exact name, because my eclipse just went south and wont even open :)

Comment: That happened to my Eclipse at work - won't get farther than the splash screen. If you figure that out I'd like to know.

I'll try the right click thing when I get home and respond with the results. Thank you.

Comment: Deleting everything Eclipse and Android (other than the actual project) and re-downloading fixed the non-opening problem. I still haven't had an opportunity to try the right-click thing with for the problem with Eclipse at home.

Comment: The issue with my eclipse was something was missing or bad file/registry for java. it could not find java.exe in my PATH, even though it existed there, so did JAVA_HOME. oh, well, I needed to rebuild any how :)

Comment: That did it. You can open with Android Layout, Menu, Resource, or XML Resources Editor and it highlights what the default is. Selecting the right one seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Right clicking the file and opening it specifically with Android Layout Editor is what solved the problem for me. Eclipse will continue to open it up with that editor after choosing that editor.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and re-installing the Android Developement Tools Plugin for eclipse at least partyl fixed the problem for me.

Strangely it worked best when completely uninstalling the plugin!?